# PHP 8 migration Fatal error: Declaration must be compatible

Tags: php, migration, php-8

We are moving forward to PHP 8 from PHP 7.4, we are facing  Declaration must be compatible Fatal error in our code to custom parameter type, we need a proper solution with less code changes.
Kindly refer below code snippet

**ERROR**

> Fatal error: Declaration of ClientReactieView::getUrlAddData(?ClientReactie $clientReactie = null) must be compatible with Overview\BaseView::getUrlAddData(?Storm\Model $model = null) in /var/www/html/system/tmp/class_client_reactie_view.php on line 102

**abstract class file : abstract_class_base_view.php**

```
<?php
 namespace Overview;
 use Storm;

 abstract class BaseView {
  
  public static function getUrlAddData(Storm\Model $model = null){
    // ...
    return $urlAddData;
  }
}
```

**Child class file : class_client_reactie_view.php**

```
<?php

  class ClientReactieView extends Overview\BaseView {

   public static function getUrlAddData(ClientReactie $clientReactie = null){
     // ...
     return $urlAddData;
   }
 }
```

**Custom parameter type class_client_reactie.php**

```
 class ClientReactie extends Storm\Model {
  // ...
 }
```

Our application is already developed & working fine with PHP 7.4, We require solution to resolve this fatal error with less code changes

Comment: change `?ClientReactie $clientReactie = null` to `?Storm\Model $model = null` in ClientReactieView class

Comment: but it will break the purpose of abstraction & custom type ClientReactie

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling your code is illogical.

The definition of `BaseView` makes a promise: you can call `getUrlAddData` and pass any instance of `Storm\Model`, or `null`.

The definition of `ClientReactieView` says that it extends `BaseView`, so inherits that promise. But then it changes that promise: you can call `getUrlAddData`, but you're not allowed to pass anything that's not a `ClientReactie`.

This is "covariance of input", and has always been forbidden for non-static methods - if `$foo instanceof BaseView` is true, then `$foo->getUrlAddData(...)` would have to accept all values that the definition in `BaseView` allowed.

What's new in PHP 8 is that this is enforced for static methods as well, so that the same guarantee applies to "late static binding" calls such as this:

```
abstract class BaseView {
  
  public static function getUrlAddData(Storm\Model $model = null){
    // ...
    return $urlAddData;
  }

  public static function doSomethingElse(Storm\Model $model = null){
    $urlAddData = static::getUrlAddData($model);
    // ...
  }
}

class ClientReactieView extends Overview\BaseView {

   public static function getUrlAddData(ClientReactie $clientReactie = null){
     // ...
     return $urlAddData;
   }
}

ClientReactieView::doSomethingElse(new Storm\Model);
// ERROR! The call goes to BaseView::doSomethingElse, which accepts any Model
// But static::getUrlAddData resolves to ClientReactieView::getUrlAddData
//  and that has an incompatible signature
```

So the correct fix is to honour the promise made by the parent class:

```
class ClientReactieView extends Overview\BaseView {

   public static function getUrlAddData(Storm\Model $model = null){
     if ( ! $model instanceof ClientReactie ) {
        // Figure out what to do with such calls
     }
     // ...
     return $urlAddData;
   }
}
```